# Which is right way to call two click event one after another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-events

I want to fire a click event on click to a button. I have written code below, both worked for me but I want to know which one is better way for same.

1st method:

```
 jQuery( "#responav li" ).click(function() {
     jQuery( "#close-icon" ).click();
    });
```

2nd method:

```
jQuery( "#responav li" ).click(function() { 
     jQuery( "#close-icon" ).trigger("click"); 
   });
```

Comment: In addition, there is also a [`.triggerHandler()` method](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/). However, this method is not equivilent to the ones you posted because `.triggerHandler()` will only trigger all handlers bound with jQuery for the event type, as the name implies...

Comment: ok, thanks for additional one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.trigger('click')` is a little more performant, since `$.click()` just runs `$.trigger('click')`.

From https://api.jquery.com/click/

> This method is a shortcut for [...] .trigger( "click" )

And from http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user.

Comment: Is this right way to call click event after a another click event directly as mentioned in 1st method ?

Comment: If you want to trigger a click on `#close-icon` after the user clicks on `#responav li`, yes.